# Cluster nearby locations to one point and leave out locations which are far

Tags: java, android-studio, cluster-analysis

I am trying to make an algorithm in which i want to cluster all the nearby coordinates i.e. latitudes and longitudes to one point and then leave out all the remaining coordinates out. When the distance between the leftover coordinates and cluster which is formed by all the nearby coordinates is reducing to a certain extent, then the leftovers should merge inside the cluster. I am very new in this kind of stuff and i would really appreciate if someone helps me with this.

For instance, for a bus tracking app, if at a bus stop, coordinates of a number of people are stored in a server with the help of location services provided by the app, these nearby coordinates should form a cluster so that when these people travel on the bus, people at other bus stops (whose coordinates will be leftovers) can track the location of the bus with the help of the cluster formed on the map. When the cluster comes near to leftover coordinates, i.e. when the bus is coming to the next bus stop, the leftover coordinates should merge inside the cluster.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Honestly saying i couldn't figure out anything yet because i have no knowledge about clustering a particular data set.

Answer (score 0):

That is not cluster analysis. You are not trying to discover unknown structure.

Rather, your structure is *predefined* (bus stop locations) and you want to assign objects to their nearest stop if it is close enough.

That is a simple neighborhood query, no statistical structure discovery. If you had a good database systems then you could do an (informal syntax) "select users where distance(user, bus stop) < maximum-distance-allowed".

Comment: So i assume that i have data of all the user locations on my database, now i want to calculate the centroid (and show one marker on the map) of all the user coordinates which are near to each other and the coordinates which are far away shall not be included in the centroid. How shall i do this?

Comment: Select the data to be included, compute the mean coordinate.

Comment: I entered some random data and created a table in MySql. The data contained some random names and latitude and longitudes taken from google maps which are accurate. Then i searched for all the coordinates which are nearby and inside a 100 metre distance using Haversine Formula. Now what i want to do is that i want to mark a single marker on my app which will denote the centroid of all the locations which are selected from the table.

Comment: Continuation of previous comment: For instance, i selected all those coordinates which are at a 100 metres distance radius from a bus stop. Now all those coordinates which are selected, have to be converted into a centroid so that we can show one single marker on the app. This centroid then will show the users the location of the BUS which stops on the bus stop. You might have guessed by now that i am trying to create a bus tracking system. Instead of directly using the drivers location i am trying to create an algorithm which will show the buses location using the riders location.

Comment: If you are working on local enough data for buses, use an UTM projection, not haversine on the sphere.